# For $f : A \to B$ smooth, $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $A$ interval, does $f' = 0$ imply that $f$ is constant?

Tags: real-analysis

An answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) claimed that an interesting mathematical mistake is believing that

> If $f$ is a smooth function with $f' = 0$, then $f$ is constant.

(For simplicity, I presuppose that both the domain and codomain are subsets of the reals.) However, this mistake seems to be due to vagueness. There is a counterexample if we permit that the domain is a union of disjoint intervals, and that the derivatives of the edge points of the intervals are left-hand/right-hand derivatives.

However, if we insist that the domain must be an interval, the implication seems to hold. Here is my attempted proof.

Let $f: A \to B$. Furthermore, $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is smooth, $A$ is an interval and $f' = 0$. Suppose that $f$ is not constant. This implies that there exist $x$ and $y$ in $A$, $x < y$, such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Because $A$ is an interval, $[x, y]$ is a subset of $A$ and $f$ is also smooth on it. Then [the mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) implies that there exists $c \in (x, y)$ such that

$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \neq 0,
$$

because $f(x) \neq f(y)$. This contradicts $f' = 0$. $\blacksquare$

Is this correct? Thank you for the feedback! :)

P.S. To explicitly satisfy all of the conditions for the mean value theorem to hold, I note that continuity is implied by smoothness, so $f$ is continuous on $[x,y]$.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct. You can also use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements). You have that $F(x)=\int_a^xf'(y)\mathrm dy=0$ and for any function $G$ with $G'=f$ you have $G(x)-G(a)=F(x)=0$, so $G(x)=G(a)$ is  constant.

Comment: This is mean value theorem in disguise as the fundamental theorem of calculus itself is an immediate consequence of the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The example in that list is worded in a very bare-bones manner. All it says is

> If $f$ is a smooth function with $df = 0$, then $f$ is constant.

This of course isn't true (hence why it's on the list). The truth is that if $f$ is a smooth function with $df = 0$, then $f$ is *locally constant.* This in particular means that for every connected component of the domain of $f$ (assuming the domain of $f$ to be an open set), $f$ takes a constant value on said connected component.

In $\mathbb R$, this is a consequence of the mean value theorem, as you showed in your post.